# Windows 7 Trusted installer using 4gb of ram and up to 50% of my cpu

Tags: windows-7, windows, automatic-update

My windows 7 updater was been bugging out since I got a fresh install of windows 7, I downloaded the patch that was meant to fix this. And I thought it did at first, the updates download and started to install and then in went crazy agian... anyone have a fix for this? ( the patch I downloaded was KB3102810 )

Answer (score 0):

It's a known-with-problems KB. unfortunately, even if it installs correctly, after a while it causes other updates to behave in the same way.

Now to install or reinstall it when it causes trouble for other updates:

1. (Uninstall the update if it's already installed)
2. Start in safemode and delete the contents of the 
   "windows\Softwaredistribution" folder. *
3. Start in normal mode
4. Install/reinstall the update
5. Restart

*This will cause for the initial scan & download of updates to take a long time first time you run windows update again, but since there is no specific fix, it's a viable workaround.

Comment: Tip: you can delete the SoftwareDistribution folder without needing to boot into safemode. Just stop the Windows Update service (wuauserv), and then delete. On Win10, the service will restart itself pretty quickly, so also need to disable and stop.

Comment: What he said, plus one thing. Hit the Start button and type cmd. Right click on cmd and Run as Administrator. Once that's open, type into it the following command "sfc /scannow" without the quotes. That can take some time. Order of hours sometimes.

Comment: Yes, there's a chance that SFC can fix some of the issues, but in this specific case it did not work on the few systems I tested on.

Comment: yeah. SFC is a general sanity check. Well, if you know this specific issue, I'll take your word for it

Answer (score 0):

#### The patch I downloaded was KB3102810

There is a new patch (KB3161608), released 21st June 2016:

> This update contains some improvements to Windows Update Client in
>   Windows 7 Service Pack 1 (SP1) and Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1. This
>   includes the following:
>
> - An optimization that addresses long scan time for updates that's reported on some computers.
> - Fix for a Windows Update error 0x8007000E on some computers while they are updating.
> - Some reliability improvements.
>
> **How to get this update**
>
> Install the [June 2016 update rollup for Windows 7 SP1 and Windows
>   Server 2008 R2 SP1 (KB3161608)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/3161608).

Source [Windows Update Client for Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2: June 2016](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3161647)